# Trigger an event when a page loads for the first time and no other time after that

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

The idea is that I want to prompt a user to change their password when the page is loaded using jQuery's:
    `$('a').trigger('click');`

The problem I am facing is that the event is triggered every time the page is loaded.

Ideally I would like to trigger the event once per login session.. What would be the best way to do so..? Post a value to the DB when I trigger the event then check the value in the db to see if it has already been triggered? This is my idea.. but I feel there may be a quicker and speedier way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: you could write a [cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to the machine which you can clear if the user logs out or closes the browser.  On page load check for the cookie and if it doesn't exist then trigger the click.  Otherwise use php to set a session var after the first load - again if the session var doesn't exist, then echo out the js code to trigger the click and then set the var

Comment: client-side? or server-side? you can use sessionStorage, if you want it client-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work with sessions you can try this:

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['saw_js'])): ?>
    <script>
        $('a').trigger('click');
    </script>
<?php endif; $_SESSION['saw_js'] = true; ?>
```

Basically, when the user logins `$_SESSION['saw_js']` is not set, so your JS code is printed. Then, it won't be anymore because the var was set.

Comment: Hi your code is correct , why is the OP not responding ?

Comment: Hey thanks. I wrote it only 20 minutes ago, I think we have to let him some time :)

Comment: for this type of code "if not set, else set", I like to do like this :

<?php if(!isset($once) && $once=True){ /* do something */}

Answer (score 1):

"Ideally I would like to trigger the event once per login session."
So...Use the Session ?

```
if(!array_key_exists('already_changed', $_SESSION)){
    //do something
```

Comment: Thanks guys cookies or sessions I suppose will do fine!

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant, but this is just example.

I dont know what is Your code structure.

```
//variable sett by result from database
<? $ask_new_password = true; ?>

var passwordRequest = <?=$ask_new_password;?>;

if(passwordRequest){

     $('a').trigger('click');
}
```